# load average de 40.5 en procesador de 4 nucleos

Tags: linux

tengo un problema para interpretar el load averague de mi sistema,  al verlo hoy tiró por la borda todo el conocimiento que tenía sobre el mismo, me explico:

Tengo 4 nucleos  y entiendo que para que esté "lleno" debería mostrarme un valor de 4.0  , pero me muestra 40.5 !!

Como debo interpretarlo? que significa un valor de 40.5 ?  , cabe aclarar que al momento de esa carga, el sistema no estaba saturado y funcionaba bien. También cabe aclarar que estoy 100% seguro que es un procesador de 4 nucleos.

Gracias.

Comment: A grandes rasgos, si tienes  4 núcleos  4.0 indica carga completa (se están usando los cuatro núcleos constantemente durante ese periodo de tiempo) . Valores superiores indican sobrecarga; los cuatro núcleos se usan constantemente pero hay procesos en espera mientras tanto. No obstante, aunque 40.5 es demasiado aparentemente, un valor puntual no significa nada por si solo, faltaría saber durante cuanto tiempo se produce esto, que procesos están detrás, etc para valorarlo adecuadamente. Un saludo.

Comment: http://aplicacionesysistemas.com/load-average-carga-de-cpu-en-linux/

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta FJSevilla.   Había olvidado por completo lo de los procesos en espera,  entonces ese valor significa eso.  Ese valor surgió luego de hacer una prueba de stress (aprox, 1000 peticiones http).   De todas formas es curioso que el rendimiento no se vio afectado.   Ese valor fue constante durante el plazo que duró dicha prueba.     Cualquier otra sugerencia es bienvenida.